# How to configure ipv6 for docker which is hosted in Amazon EC2?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, ipv6, amazon-ecs

I have been facing issue in configuring ipv6 in docker which is on AWS EC2. If i run ping6 google.com is working from the EC2 host. But the same not working inside the container but ipv4 is working on both.

Note: I don't get any specific error.

I have tried the steps mentioned in the below docker document but no luck.

https://docs.master.dockerproject.org/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/ipv6/

Comment: Seems like this should be on Superuser or Serverfault but I'm not sure which one.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have posted in serverfault as well.